# Find and replace pdftotext generated image character in .txt file

Tags: php, shell, pdf, urlencode, pdftotext

I used PHP's pdftotext to create a lot of .txt files from pdf's.

Used it like this, which works perfectly for all the text parts in all the files:

```
system("pdftotext -raw dir/$pdf_file 2>&1");
```

**THE PROBLEM**

However, in the new .txt file all the images from the pdf's appear as:

- 'FF' when opening the file in FTP
- char '%0C' with urlencode in the browser (fopen)
- an arrow up without urlencode (fopen)
- ^L, when using less on the command line (in CentOs 7), where even **sed 's/^L//g'** on a single filename is not working.

So, in all those views, I get different ways to work with this weird char.

**THE QUESTION**

After trying so many code for a week, I am still looking for a way to find and delete this weird image char from all the .txt files.

Is there a solution for this?

Or, what is the smart thing to do here? Working with a php file with code, or on the command line? I am kind of lost on this one now.

Comment: That's not a PHP command; it's a system command, for which the man page is here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext - which states "Use of raw mode is no longer recommended." ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code convention whilst printing Plain Text is that FF usually means FormFeed it is a Control Code to the printer

`↑  12  00/12   14  %0C  FF   (CtrL=^L)  FORM FEED` (Page Break)

This is a way to indicate / eject an End Of Page, so you should see one at the division between pages.

There is a switch to remove/exclude them so try ,

```
system("pdftotext -raw -nopgbrk dir/$pdf_file 2>&1");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could have thought of that myself, but now it is a great lesson as well! Thanks again!

Comment: I was reading up on your answer, and it made me realize this is such a great insightful one. I should have tried the 'nopgbrk' option first of course, but I hope others will find their solution with your answer as well.

Comment: ps. not to mention the odds and fun-fact of two persons with the same initials interacting with each other here. Would be a cool thing if @stackoverflow created a Badge for that! Maybe the 'Namesake' Badge? Could be a nice one to design!